# python regex - last occurance before EOL

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of strings from a log file that I need to parse:

```
    timestamp - user not found : user1
    timestamp - exception in xyz.security.plugin: global error : low memory
```

I want to capture the text between "-" and the last ":".

Currently I am using r' -(.*?)\n' which captures the string till the EOL. Please bear in mind that there may be more than 2 colons used in the string. I need to capture till the very last colon used before EOL.
Also, if there are no ":" colons in the string, it should take EOL as the ending sequence.

thanks.

EDIT: better examples;

```
    2011-07-29 07:29:44,112 [TP-Processor10] ERROR springsecurity.GrailsDaoImpl  - User not found: sspm
    2011-07-29 09:01:05,850 [TP-Processor3] ERROR transaction.JDBCTransaction  - JDBC commit failed
    2011-07-29 08:32:00,353 [TP-Processor1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [POST] /webapp/user/index - parameters: runtime exception
```

Comment: In order to distinguish between the `-` within the timestamps, inside `[TP-Processor..]` and the one before the actual error message, can we assume that that one is always surrounded by spaces, and the other ones aren't?

Comment: Got it!

        r' -(.*):|$'
works perfectly and fulfills all my requirements. Thanks to all who helped me. regex can be quite a mf. o.0

@Tim: In my code, I took the "-" as the staring string as it is there in all the lines. I want to capture the error details and then  put up a counter for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

for line in open('logfile.log'):
    match = re.search(r'-(.*):', line)
    if match:
        print match.group(1)
    else:
        match = re.search(r'-(.*)', line)
        if match:
            print match.group(1)
        else:
            print 'No match in line', line.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks. but there may be multiple colons in the line. I need to capture the very last. Also, in case there is no colon at all, it needs to capture the EOL.

Comment: In your question you said you want to capture the text between "-" and the last ":" - that's what my snippet does.

Comment: you are correct. my bad. thanks. ^_^
now, I just need to capture EOl in case of no colons.

Comment: Got it!

        r' -(.*):|$'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"(?<=-).*(?=:[^:]*$)"
```

It matches between a `-` and the last `:` in the current line. If there is no colon, it won't match at all, therefore you can do:

```
r = re.compile("(?<=-).*(?=:[^:]*$)")
result = r.search(mystring) 
if result:
    match = result.group(0)
else:
    match = "\n"
```

This does what you *said* ("if there is no colon, match EOL"), if you *meant* "if there is no colon, match **until** EOL", then a single regex will do:

```
r = re.compile("(?<=-)(?:[^:]*$|.*(?=:[^:]*$))")
```

Comment: Thanks. The regex you gave wasn't working for me. But tweaking it gave me what I wanted. r' -(.*)(?=:[^:]*$)' works for my requirements. Is there any way of adding the EOL in the same regex? If not, I'll try the is/else loop you suggested.

Comment: What do you mean by "wasn't working"? I changed the regex so you now don't need to access group no. 1, but the entire match result (group 0).

Comment: my mistake. sorry. I meant until EOL.

Answer (score 1):

`r'^.+ -(.+):.*$'` does the trick for me.

This works because the `(.+)` is greedy. Check the Python documentation for `re` [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) - in particular, for `*`, `+`, and `?`.

Comment: Thanks. This actually gets the last "-" used in the string.
so for the string;
`2011-07-29 08:32:00,353 [TP-Processor1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [POST] /connectwebapp/user/index - parameters: runtime`
its saving only "parameters".

The output I am looking for is, "Exception occurred when processing request: [POST] /connectwebapp/user/index - parameters"

Also, in lines where there is no ":", it is failing.